# Show that a system of 4 equations has a unique solution

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations and I would like your help to show that it has a unique solution with respect to $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$.

More precisely, let the system be
$$
\begin{cases}
c\lambda_1=\lambda_3a\\
b\lambda_1=\lambda_2a\\
\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
where it is assumed that $a,b,c,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are **strictly** positive and $a+b+c=1$.

**Question:** I want to show that $\lambda_1=a, \lambda_2=b, \lambda_3=c$ is the unique solution of the system. I tried various substitution routes but couldn't come up with any clean steps. Could you help?

Comment: The solution is *not* unique. If we take your solution, then the system is reduced to a single equation $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1$, where we have infinitely many solutions "with respect to" $\lambda_i$.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your comment. Could you clarify more? Also in relation to the answer below. Thanks

Comment: $4$ equations ???

Comment: You have changed the system now. It used to be four equations in the six variables $a,b,c,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, which did not have a unique solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get $$\lambda_2=\frac{b}{a}\lambda_1$$
$$\lambda_3=\frac{c}{a}\lambda_1$$ so
$$\lambda_1+\frac{b}{a}\lambda_1+\frac{c}{a}\lambda_1=1$$
Can you proceed?
From this equation (using that $$a+b+c=1$$) we get $$\lambda_1=a$$

Comment: Thanks, got it. I'm confused with the comment I received above about the fact that the solution provided is not unique. Even if it is not your comment, could you clarify? Thanks

Comment: With $$ \lambda_1=a$$ you will get $$\lambda_2= \frac{b}{a}\cdot a=b$$ and $$\lambda_3=\frac{c}{a}\cdot a=c$$

Comment: And this was and is not my comment!

Comment: Can you read? $$a,b,c,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$$ are strictly POSITIVE!

Comment: Ok all things are ok!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Multiplying both sides of the last equation gives
$$a = a \lambda_1 + a \lambda_2 + a \lambda_3,$$
and substituting using the first two equations gives
$$a = a \lambda_1 + (b \lambda_1) + (c \lambda_1) .$$

> Factoring gives $a = (a + b + c) \lambda_1 = \lambda_1$. Now, the first two equations tell us that $\lambda_1$ determines $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of the system is

$$\begin{vmatrix}c&0&-a\\b&-a&0\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=-a(a+b+c)\ne0,$$

hence the solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Rescaling the variables by the factors $a,b,c$ respectively,

$$\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3,\\a\mu_1+b\mu_2+c\mu_3=1$$ is trivial to solve.